# easymock, mock returning a mock

Tags: java, easymock

I am testing my Java code using EasyMock.

The piece of code that I want to mock looks like this:

```
requestInfo = mupClient.newEnqueueRequestCall().call(requestArgs);
```

The way I am mocking this is:

```
expect(mupClient.newEnqueueRequestCall()).andReturn(enqueueRequestCall);
final Capture<EnqueueRequestArgs> captureRequestArgs = 
                         new Capture<EnqueueRequestArgs>();
expect(mupClient.newEnqueueRequestCall().call(capture(captureRequestArgs))).
                         andThrow(new MUPCoralException("an exception"));
```

But `requestInfo` is always `null`. Even if I change the `.andThrow()` part to `.andReturn(new RequestInfo())`, it is still `null`.

I checked the other similar post but that did not work. Now was I able to comment on it and hence creating a new question.

ANSWER:
add all mock'd objects in `replay`! Example `replay(mockObj1, mockObj2, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(mupClient.newEnqueueRequestCall()).andReturn(enqueueRequestCall);
final Capture<EnqueueRequestArgs> captureRequestArgs = 
                          new Capture<EnqueueRequestArgs>();
expect(enqueueRequestCall.call(capture(captureRequestArgs))).
                          andThrow(new MUPCoralException("an exception"));
```

The problem is that your `enqueRequestCall` should return `requestInfo`. `mupClient` will return `enqueueRequestCall` only after you call `replay` method from easymock.

Comment: I had tried that too. I figured out the problem. I did not add the mock in the replay. that worked. example, i had `replay(mock1)` while it should be `replay(mock1, mock2)`. Thank you!